# System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule does not implement IHttpHandlerFactory or IHttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, nopcommerce

In our Website this error is come every 5 minutes.
And I don't know from where its call.
we need robots.txt without this error.

our application automatic call http://www.xyzName.com/content/images/thumbs/robots.txt
And show below exception

> System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule does not implement
> IHttpHandlerFactory or IHttpHandler.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.

This is the method which automatic generate the robots.txt file when this method is call. but the problem is from some where in application robots.txt call automatically.

```
  public ActionResult RobotsTextFile()
            {
                //Default Code blocked by Nilesh
                if (_storeContext.CurrentStore.Url.Contains("tk"))
                {
                    const string newLine = "\r\n"; //Environment.NewLine
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("User-agent: *");
                    sb.Append(newLine);
                    sb.Append("Disallow: /");
                    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    var disallowPaths = new List<string>
                                        {
                                            "/bin/",
                                            "/content/files/",
                                            "/content/files/exportimport/",
                                            "/country/getstatesbycountryid",
                                            "/install",
                                            "/setproductreviewhelpfulness",
                                        };
                    var localizableDisallowPaths = new List<string>
                                                   {
                                                       "/addproducttocart/catalog/",
                                                       "/addproducttocart/details/",
                                                       "/backinstocksubscriptions/manage",
                                                       "/boards/forumsubscriptions",
                                                       "/boards/forumwatch",
                                                       "/boards/postedit",
                                                       "/boards/postdelete",
                                                       "/boards/postcreate",
                                                       "/boards/topicedit",
                                                       "/boards/topicdelete",
                                                       "/boards/topiccreate",
                                                       "/boards/topicmove",
                                                       "/boards/topicwatch",
                                                       "/cart",
                                                       "/checkout",
                                                       "/checkout/billingaddress",
                                                       "/checkout/completed",
                                                       "/checkout/confirm",
                                                       "/checkout/shippingaddress",
                                                       "/checkout/shippingmethod",
                                                       "/checkout/paymentinfo",
                                                       "/checkout/paymentmethod",
                                                       "/clearcomparelist",
                                                       "/compareproducts",
                                                       "/customer/avatar",
                                                       "/customer/activation",
                                                       "/customer/addresses",
                                                       "/customer/changepassword",
                                                       "/customer/checkusernameavailability",
                                                       "/customer/downloadableproducts",
                                                       "/customer/info",
                                                       "/deletepm",
                                                       "/emailwishlist",
                                                       "/inboxupdate",
                                                       "/newsletter/subscriptionactivation",
                                                       "/onepagecheckout",
                                                       "/order/history",
                                                       "/orderdetails",
                                                       "/passwordrecovery/confirm",
                                                       "/poll/vote",
                                                       "/privatemessages",
                                                       "/returnrequest",
                                                       "/returnrequest/history",
                                                       "/rewardpoints/history",
                                                       "/sendpm",
                                                       "/sentupdate",
                                                       "/shoppingcart/productdetails_attributechange",
                                                       "/subscribenewsletter",
                                                       "/topic/authenticate",
                                                       "/viewpm",
                                                       "/uploadfileproductattribute",
                                                       "/uploadfilecheckoutattribute",
                                                       "/wishlist",
                                                   };
    
    
                    const string newLine = "\r\n"; //Environment.NewLine
                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("User-agent: *");
                    sb.Append(newLine);
                    //sitemaps
                    if (_localizationSettings.SeoFriendlyUrlsForLanguagesEnabled)
                    {
                        //URLs are localizable. Append SEO code
                        foreach (var language in _languageService.GetAllLanguages(storeId: _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id))
                        {
                            sb.AppendFormat("Sitemap: {0}{1}/sitemap.xml", _storeContext.CurrentStore.Url, language.UniqueSeoCode);
                            sb.Append(newLine);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //localizable paths (without SEO code)
                        sb.AppendFormat("Sitemap: {0}sitemap.xml", _storeContext.CurrentStore.Url);
                        sb.Append(newLine);
                    }
    
                    //usual paths
                    foreach (var path in disallowPaths)
                    {
                        sb.AppendFormat("Disallow: {0}", path);
                        sb.Append(newLine);
                    }
                    //localizable paths (without SEO code)
                    foreach (var path in localizableDisallowPaths)
                    {
                        sb.AppendFormat("Disallow: {0}", path);
                        sb.Append(newLine);
                    }
                    if (_localizationSettings.SeoFriendlyUrlsForLanguagesEnabled)
                    {
                        //URLs are localizable. Append SEO code
                        foreach (var language in _languageService.GetAllLanguages(storeId: _storeContext.CurrentStore.Id))
                        {
                            foreach (var path in localizableDisallowPaths)
                            {
                                sb.AppendFormat("Disallow: {0}{1}", language.UniqueSeoCode, path);
                                sb.Append(newLine);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
                }
                return null;
            }
```

And In RouteProvider we add below line to map the route.

```
 routes.MapRoute("robots.txt","robots.txt",new { controller = "Common", action ="RobotsTextFile" },new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

It comes in every 5 minuets. we use amazon server for CDN, get Images from there.

Is there any possibility that amazon called this 'http://www.xyzName.com/content/images/thumbs/robots.txt' url?

Comment: but we need robots.txt file

Comment: where i need to put that line..?immediately after <add name="RobotsTxt" path="robots.txt" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />

Comment: sorry sir , not working... :(

Comment: uncomment   <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
      <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" /> this line in web config..but still got same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove (or comment out) this line from your web.config For generating `robot.txt`

```
<add name="RobotsTxt" path="robots.txt" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

And uncomment the following lines

```
<remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
<add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue after a recent publish of a Web API that I had recently changed the assembly name. I had no robots.txt file, so the above answers were not relevant to me. Anyway, as a solution, I simply cleaned out the folder on the server and republished.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue on a fresh deployment to Server 2016. In the end, I actually commented out the handler mapping for URLRoutingModule and it worked. My guess is it was conflicting with something already set on the machine level.

```
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <handlers>
            <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
            <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
            <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
            <!--<remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0"/>
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition=""/>-->
            <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
```